# TestNG library missing in new SeleniumWebdriver java project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I am learning to use testNG and this is my first project with it. I added testNG dependencies to the POM. I chose not to instal testNG from the marketplace.

Below is my output. When I however on @Test, there was no option to import testNG library. How do I fix this please?

```
package ui;

public class LoginTest {
    
    @Test
    public void loginTest()

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` manually at the top of your file.

Although as far as I understand, you're asking why an autocomplete suggestion is not being presented. If you're using IntelliJ you can start by looking into if your maven project is setup properly or not, from this official guide by them: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html and ensure that dependencies are loaded.

Comment: Thanks @oturan, Importing the annotations doesn't add TestNG library.